# Why DataTable.Select sorts the data by default

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset with the following data

```
Name          Value    Percent
0-3 months    0        0
3-12 months   0        0
1-5 years     1234.12  28
5-10 years    13144.11 68
10-15 years   0        0
Over 15 years 1233.44  14
Other Income  2245.12
```

when I try

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsMaturity.Tables[0].Select("name not like 'Other%'"))
{
    TotalValue += double.Parse(dr["Value"].ToString());
}
```

Edit: Actually, similar to the above code. I am using the similar loop to add the data to display bucket which eventually writes to the chart.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsMaturity.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //Add to the display bucket
}
```

I get the data sorted like:

```
0-3 months
10-15 years
1-5 years
3-12 months
5-10 years
Over 15 years
```

Why? How can I have the data unsorted? This is critical since I show the data in my chart object. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you force the ordering, I don't think it will be altered.

Comment: Seems your data is being ordered by first column, as text. But, why this matters?

Comment: I didn't force any ordering, this is coming from database in default order. The ordering matters to user.

Answer (score 2):

[dataTable.Select(filterExpression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/det4aw50.aspx) does not guarantee a sort order. As the documentation says, you should use one fo the other overloads to supply your sort order.

In our experiment, the result set was ordered by the filter column, but I would not trust later versions of .NET to behave the same way (as it's not documented that way).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, the answer is:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable();
```

instead of

```
dataTable.Select();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why/how to resolve this without altering the original resultset but here is my workaround:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsMaturity.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (!dr["Name"].ToString().StartsWith("Other "))
    {
        // adding it to display bucket
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed! This is pretty annoying... I'm having the same problem.

If you have .net 3.5+ you can use `Linq` to filter rows:

```
var rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => !((string)r["Name"]).StartsWith("Other")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsMaturity.Tables[0].Select("name not like 'Other%'", "column_to_sort_by"))
{
    TotalValue += double.Parse(dr["Value"].ToString());
}
```

where `column_to_sort_by` is a column that sorts in the proper order.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the data from?

If it is coming from a database then I would check and see what the order is when you run the query manually.

Jeff

Comment: The data is created by a procedure and it adds them to return dataset. I don't have access to modify the procedure. I get the data and simply want to show it in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is already sorted in the database that might be why it appears sorted.  The data you presented looks sorted by Name.  Is that how it is in the database?

Comment: It is not a simple select statement and order by clause type of query. Database creates these rows by some rule. The dataset I mentioned is what I get from the database. Now how can I use select without rearranging the records from original dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach to this. If we have to use SELECT, and not LINQ like suggested in previous answers, we should temporarily add a new index column, do the select and sort by the index, and then remove the column.

An extension method for this might look something like this:

```
    public static DataRow[] NotSortedSelect(this DataTable table, string filter)
    {
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn
        {
            ColumnName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            DataType = typeof(int)
        };

        table.Columns.Add(column);
        int rowid = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
           dr[column] = rowid++;
        }

        var rows =  table.Select(filter, $"{column.ColumnName} ASC");
        var newDataTable = rows.CopyToDataTable();
        newDataTable.Columns.Remove(column.ColumnName);
        
        return newDataTable.Select();
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
    dsMaturity.Tables[0].NotSortedSelect("name not like 'Other%'")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DataView dv = datSource.DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = strFilter;
```

If you want the data sorted than use `dv.Sort = "..."`

```
DataTable datTarget = dv.ToTable();
```